# _PublishedWebsites dont include webfonts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webfonts, build-script

I am a bit baffled, I have an MVC3 project in Visual Studio 2010, and as part of our build script which outputs the compilation to an "output" directory.

This all works fine, however we are now using webfonts as part of our site and no matter what I try, the webfonts never find their way to the _PublishedWebsites folder, even with Copy To Output Directory just puts it in the general output folder not the _PublishedWebsites one...

So am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem too. When your project is open, select all the webfont files in Solution Explorer. Right click on any, and select "Properties" from a context menu. In the collective properties dialog that will appear, set "Build Action" to "Content". This will tell the package assembler to treat these files as content indeed.